# Does Kafka Cluster give disaster recovery advantage?

Tags: apache-kafka, disaster-recovery

A Kafka cluster provides high availability, but does it also provide some disaster recovery protection?

Specifically, if say one of your topic files was somehow corrupted or deleted on one server, can you recover from this with the topic files on your other servers in the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Topic replication accounts for these scenarios, yes.

If topics have a replication factor of higher than one and you have unclean leader election disabled, then it's highly unlikely for a topic or partition to become non-recoverable.